# How to get latest record per user whilst filtering on another (annotate?)

Tags: python, django

I have a model Baz.  I want to get a list of the latest baz (descending order) for each user_bar, filtering on a single user_foo.

```
class Baz(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True, related_name='user_foo')
    bar = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True, related_name='user_bar')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    created = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

So for example say there are Baz records, and the filter is for "tom":

```
id  foo     bar     content
--  ---     ---     -------
1   tom     dick    some text
2   tom     harry   some more text
3   dick    tom     even more text 
4   tom     dick    last text ever
```

In this case the query would return:

```
id  foo     bar     content
--  ---     ---     -------
4   tom     dick    last text ever
2   tom     harry   some more text
```

...assuming that the records were created in order.

This will get the records, but there will be multiple records for each user_bar (I want to get the latest for each user_bar):

```
Baz.objects.filter(foo=request.user).order_by('-created')
```

(Update) I tried this:

```
Baz.objects.filter(foo=request.user).values('bar').
annotate(Max('created')).order_by('-created')
```

...but it does not contain all the fields:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'content'
```

This is close to what I want, but I it does not order the records by latest first because bar takes precedence in the ordering:

```
Baz.objects.filter(foo=request.user).order_by('bar', 
    '-created').distinct('bar')
```

This does the job, but seems overly complicated:

```
ids = Baz.objects.filter(foo=request.user).order_by('bar', 
    '-created').distinct('bar').values_list('id')
Baz.objects.filter(id__in=ids).order_by('-created')
```